# Which databases support synchronous replication (Java / embeddable preferred)?

Tags: java, database, derby, h2, database-replication

I'm looking for a database that supports synchronous replication and fail over.  Automatic fail over would be ideal, but manual fail over would be acceptable.  I'd also prefer something I can bundle with a Java application.

[H2 looks like it might work](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) using the clustering / high availability mode. My setup would be low capacity ( < 10 simultaneous users, minimal data) and on a LAN (low latency), but a need for quick fail over with consistent data.

Are there any other databases I should look at?  Are there any other types of solutions I should explore?  I've come across things like DRBD, CouchDB, Terracotta, etc., but they seem like overkill for what I need (and designed for high capacity workloads).  I'll have another look if someone can make a case for any of them though.

Edit: To clarify, I'd like a database that can be embedded to simplify development / testing, but would run it in client / server mode to facilitate fail over.

Comment: I can't see how you would do an failover with an *embedded* database. If the embedded database went down so did your application (because it's a single process). So how do you plan to "fail over" your application that is no longer running?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited my question to clarify.  I would run it in client / server mode if needed.  Running in embedded mode is less important to me than being able to embed (bundle) the database server in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derby has some replication functionality: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminreplication.html

Comment: That's asynchronous, shipped log replication though.  That makes it possible to lose transactions which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Derby also supports two-phase commit. So you could implement this at the application level by updating both your databases within an XA transaction. Then the commit wouldn't succeed unless both databases were updated.